# How to parse this simple XML?

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to parse thhis simple XML:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """
<ns2:Request xmlns:ns2="urn://www.example.com">
    <ns2:User>
        <ns2:Name>John</ns2:Name>
        <ns2:Surname>Snow</ns2:Surname>
        <ns2:Email>joihn.show@gmail.com</ns2:Email>
        <ns2:Birthday>2005-10-23T04:00:00+03:00</ns2:Birthday>
    </ns2:User>
</ns2:Request>
"""

namespaces = {"ns2": "urn://www.example.com"}

xml = ET.fromstring(data)

name = xml.find("ns2:Email", namespaces)  # returns None
```

`Name` is read as None. The code above does not works as expected. How to parse single `Name`, `Surname`, `Email` and `Birthday` fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to make sure you navigate through the XML hierarchy and use the correct namespace when searching for the elements

```
# You need to search for the User element first and then get the child elements
user_element = xml.find("ns2:User", namespaces)

name = user_element.find("ns2:Name", namespaces).text
surname = user_element.find("ns2:Surname", namespaces).text
email = user_element.find("ns2:Email", namespaces).text
birthday = user_element.find("ns2:Birthday", namespaces).text

print(f"Name: {name}")
print(f"Surname: {surname}")
print(f"Email: {email}")
print(f"Birthday: {birthday}")
```

It will output

```
Name: John
Surname: Snow
Email: joihn.show@gmail.com
Birthday: 2005-10-23T04:00:00+03:00
```

Answer (score 2):

`find` searches the subelements if only an element name is specified, i.e. it doesn't recurse into their subelements. You need to specify the full path

```py
name = xml.find("ns2:User/ns2:Email", namespaces)
```

Or you can use the `//` axis:

```py
name = xml.find(".//ns2:Email", namespaces)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Choroba answer, your find() needs the path or iter() from root down. Alternative you can use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = """
<ns2:Request xmlns:ns2="urn://www.example.com">
    <ns2:User>
        <ns2:Name>John</ns2:Name>
        <ns2:Surname>Snow</ns2:Surname>
        <ns2:Email>joihn.show@gmail.com</ns2:Email>
        <ns2:Birthday>2005-10-23T04:00:00+03:00</ns2:Birthday>
    </ns2:User>
</ns2:Request>
"""

df = pd.read_xml(data)
print(df.T)
```

Output:

```
                                  0
Name                           John
Surname                        Snow
Email          joihn.show@gmail.com
Birthday  2005-10-23T04:00:00+03:00
```